# Symbol was not found when using tmpaccountsum variable in form

Tags: axapta, x++, microsoft-dynamics

In the ReqTransPO form I want to use the tmpAccountSum table to store some values in which I later need to filter my grid.

In the classdeclaration I declared:
tmpAccountSum mytable;

In a helper method I have:

```
 //Store data in tmptable
 ttsbegin;
 mytable.AccountNum        = _reqTrans.RefId;
 mytable.Txt               = _reqPo.RefId;
 mytable.Voucher           = enum2str(_prodstatus);
 mytable.insert();
 ttscommit;
```

I don't get an error on 'mytable' but can't really use it / it's not initialized. If I add a watch in debug I see:
    Error: Symbol "mytable" was not found

If I declare mytable locally it works ok.
Guess I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My extrasensory perception tells me, that your helper method is `static`.

Static methods do not have access to instance variables declared in `classDeclaration`.